# How Do I Set My Fedora KDE 33 Workstation To NOT Suspend Upon Lid Close?

Tags: fedora, kde, suspend, sleep

My Fedora KDE 33 Workstation (Old Sony Vaio Book) suspends when I close it. I would like to listen to music with the lid closed, so how should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*System Settings* → *Power Management* → *Energy Saving* → in all three tabs (*On AC Power/On Battery/On Low Battery*) set *When laptop lid closed* to *Do nothing*.

[image]